# Way it ignore entity reference resolving?

Tags: java, parsing, xerces

I'm using Java 6 and the latest version of Xerces.  I'm trying to parse an HTML document that begins like this ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and later references the entity "&raquo".  Parsing dies with the exception ...

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "raquo" was referenced, but not declared. 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:249) 
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284) 
    at com.myco.myproject.util.XmlUtilities.getStringAsDocument(XmlUtilities.java:147) 
    at com.myco.myproject.util.NetUtilities.getUrlAsDocument(NetUtilities.java:65) 
    at com.myco.myproject.parsers.impl.AbstractMetromixParser.parsePage(AbstractMetromixParser.java:107) 
    at com.myco.myproject.parsers.impl.AbstractMetromixParser.getEvents(AbstractMetromixParser.java:76) 
    at com.myco.myproject.domain.EventFeed.refresh(EventFeed.java:81) 
    at com.myco.myproject.domain.EventFeed.getEvents(EventFeed.java:72) 
    at com.myco.myproject.parsers.impl.MetromixParserTest.testParser(MetromixParserTest.java:21) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) 
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44) 
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15) 
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41) 
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20) 
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28) 
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74) 
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83) 
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72) 
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231) 
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184) 
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) 
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) 
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236) 
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174) 
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50) 
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) 
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467) 
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683) 
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390) 
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Is there any way to tell the parser to ignore these types of entities it cannot resolve?  If not, what resolver do I have to plugin?

**Edit**: Here is how I am parsing the HTML, which is actually XHTML.  I pass the String through JSoup to clean it up before I attempt the below ...

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(false);
    factory.setExpandEntityReferences(false);
    final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    final InputSource s = new InputSource(new StringReader(str));
    org.w3c.dom.Document result = builder.parse(s);
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser, not an XML parser. HTML is not XML.

Comment: Ah, I falsely assumed people knew what JSoup was, but the JSoup parser I'm using converts messy HTML into well-formed XHTML

Comment: I didn't see any reference to JSoup before your edit, apologies if I missed it.

Comment: Can you provide a sample snippet of the HTML that is being passed to the code?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from *1.10.3* version JSoup provides the [W3CDom](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/helper/W3CDom.html) helper class which allows you to convert your `org.jsoup.nodes.Document` directly to the `org.w3c.dom.Document`.

Consider the following example:

```
String str =
        "<!DOCTYPE html>" +
        "<html>" +
        "<dody>" +
        "<div>&raquo; example</div>" +
        "</dody>" +
        "</html>";

Document document = Jsoup.parse(str);
W3CDom w3cDom = new W3CDom();
org.w3c.dom.Document result = w3cDom.fromJsoup(document);
```